# I turned a directory into a git repo. How to undo that?

Tags: git, shell

I am a beginner and I was playing around with git. Now whenever I start my command shell, it always says "master" at the prompt: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3xVx.jpg).

How do I make it go back?

Comment: master is the current branch that you are in. You want to erase this branch?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. You can just copy & paste, it's easier to read.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+git+init

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you ran `git init` on your home directory. What this did was turn your home directory into a git repository, and your shell is configured to give you git information when you are in a git repository.

To confirm this type `ls -a`. This will list all the hidden "dot" directories in your current directory. If you see one named `.git`, it confirms your current directory is a git repo. If you were just playing around, and don't want your home directory to be a repo anymore, you can simply delete the `.git` directory. Anything you saved (committed) using git will also be gone when you do that, so be sure that's what you want.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Or `ls -d .git`. (`ls -a` might produce a *lot* of output if your home directory is as cluttered as mine is.)

Comment: Good point. But as she is learning, I think it is better not to hide too much with the magic of expert commands :)

Comment: I tried deleting it as rmv .git/ but it doesn't let me!

Comment: I don't see it in my folders ... how can I delete it?  :(

Comment: I did it! rm -r .git

Comment: nice! I was hesitant to give you the `rm -r` command because you say you are a beginner and if you do it wrong you can delete a lot of files you didn't want to delete :)

Comment: @Inigo True, but `rm -r` is (nearly) the only way to delete a directory and everything under it, which is what's necessary in this case. Having said that, Inigo, `rm -r` can be dangerous. A typo can nuke your home directory.

Comment: @CarolinaCelestineMeoux if this solved your problem let me know by accepting the answer. Otherwise let me know if there's still something amiss.